# Simplify block reference declaration using typedefs

Tags: objective-c

I'm working through Advanced Mac OS X Programming book and one exercise has me stumbled.

**Use typedefs to simplify the following block reference declaration:**

```
int (^(*(^get_block_factory_funcptr)(void))(int))(void);
```

Here's how I understand the declaration:

Function not taking arguments, returns a block which returns a void pointer, which is a pointer to a function that takes int for an argument and returns a block which has no arguments, returns an int.

Now given that, I have these 2 typedefs

```
typedef void *(^get_block_factory_funcptr)(void);
typedef int (^myBlock(int))(void);
```

However I have no idea how to combine them to a single declaration, any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading it correctly, it's a block that returns a function pointer that returns a block.  The name is a hint.

One way to figure it out is to start with the end result and work backwards.  Or, start from the inside and work outwards.

What is `get_block_factory_funcptr`?  It's a block:

```
MyBlock get_block_factory_funcptr;
```

What does it do?  It takes a void and it returns a "Block Factory" function pointer.  Let's declare `MyBlock`:

```
typedef FactoryFuncPtr (^MyBlock)(void);
```

What is `FactoryFuncPtr`?  It takes an `int` and returns another block:

```
typedef OuterBlock (*FactoryFuncPtr)(int);
```

What is `OuterBlock`?  It takes a `void` and returns an `int`:

```
typedef int (^OuterBlock)(void);
```

Those are the declarations in reverse order.

Edit: A working example.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef int (^OuterBlock)(void);
typedef OuterBlock (*FactoryFuncPtr)(int);
typedef FactoryFuncPtr (^MyBlock)(void);

OuterBlock factory(int foo) {
    return ^ {
        printf("A block with %d\n", foo);
        return 123;
    };
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        int (^(*(^get_block_factory_funcptr)(void))(int))(void) = ^ {
            return &factory;
        };

        MyBlock myBlock = get_block_factory_funcptr;
        FactoryFuncPtr foo = myBlock();
        OuterBlock bar = foo(999);
        int baz = bar();
        printf("Final %d\n", baz);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given what you posted I should be able to do the following: `FactoryFuncPtr x;` and then do: `int (^(*(^get_block_factory_funcptr)(void))(int))(void) = x;`. But this results in an error about an incompatible assignment.

Comment: @rmaddy `get_block_factory_funcptr` is a block.  `x` is a function pointer.  Try `x = get_block_factory_funcptr();`

Comment: I thought the idea was that by using the typedefs, you could assign one to the other. Can you complete your answer to show how the typedefs are actually equivalent to the original declaration?

Comment: OK, I see my mistake. I should have done: `MyBlock x;`, not `FactoryFuncPtr x;`. I was reading the `typedef` incorrectly. Very good.

Comment: It's a shame that such a good answer to a complicated question will hardly be recognized. SO seems to reward simple answers to trivial questions that are more easily understood by the masses.